# facebook comment url cross domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

To add comment on your own website by `facebook` you can use:

```
<div data-href="http://domain.com" class="fb-comments fb_iframe_widget" data-colorscheme="light" data-numposts="100" fb-xfbml-state="rendered">
```

which is useful. but can I change `domain.com` to a domain that does not belong to me such as: `http://bbc.com`

If I can put what ever url, then how does facebook prevent me from misleading url?

Answer (score 0):

The href is used for 2 things :
1. the id to store the comments data on. so in that case you can write any uniq id.
2. the actual source where the comments are. when someone comments it usally posts the comments on he's/her timeline. clicking on that post would lead to the url specified.